# How to right align text in ImGui Columns?

Tags: c++, imgui

Suppose I create a table with the following:

```
ImGui::Columns(3);

ImGui::Text("Header 1");
ImGui::NextColumn();
ImGui::Text("Header 2");
ImGui::NextColumn();
ImGui::Text("Header 3");
ImGui::NextColumn();

ImGui::Text("1");
ImGui::NextColumn();
ImGui::Text("2");
ImGui::NextColumn();
ImGui::Text("3");
ImGui::NextColumn();

ImGui::Columns(1);
```

How can I get the text in the second row (1, 2, and 3) to be right aligned in the column? I've seen `CalcItemWidth` and `CalcTextSize`, but I can't figure out how they work within a multi-column line.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I received help in the ImGui Discord channel and came up with this solution:

```
ImGui::NextColumn();
std::string text = "1";
ImGui::SetCursorPosX(ImGui::GetCursorPosX() + ImGui::GetColumnWidth() - ImGui::CalcTextSize(text.c_str()).x 
    - ImGui::GetScrollX() - 2 * ImGui::GetStyle().ItemSpacing.x);
ImGui::Text("%s", text);
```

Edit: @FabriceMollo's answer is better.

Answer (score 2):

Nearly same code than iHowell answer but new x position should be checked against current position value in order to be well window-border aligned (text will then be right-clipped).
In code:

```
ImGui::NextColumn();
std::string text = "1";
auto posX = (ImGui::GetCursorPosX() + ImGui::GetColumnWidth() - ImGui::CalcTextSize(text.c_str()).x 
    - ImGui::GetScrollX() - 2 * ImGui::GetStyle().ItemSpacing.x);
if(posX > ImGui::GetCursorPosX())
  ImGui::SetCursorPosX(posX);
ImGui::Text("%s", text);
```

Comment: To be even more clear you could rephrase "same answer than previously" because I have no idea what you are referring to. But the code is somewhat helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is better

```
int your_column = 0;
std::string text = "ID";
auto column1_x = (ImGui::GetCursorPosX() + ImGui::GetColumnWidth(your_column) * 0.5 - ImGui::CalcTextSize(text.c_str()).x);
if (column1_x > ImGui::GetCursorPosX())
    ImGui::SetCursorPosX(column1_x);
ImGui::Text("%s", text.c_str());
```

Comment: You should add some explanation and/or citations supporting your claim that, "this is better."